# MySQL set column value if another column's new value is different than current one

Tags: mysql

I have a table that has a column `mycolumn` and a column that has a boolean flag `mycolumn_is_new`. I want to set the second one to true when an UPDATE query changes the value of the first one. The user can type the same data or new data.

I have come up with this query, but `mycolumn_is_new` is always set to false :

```
UPDATE mytable SET
    mycolumn = '1234',
    mycolumn_is_new = IF(mycolumn <> '1234', TRUE, FALSE)
WHERE id = 321
```

Is it possible check the new and old value in a single query?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All expressions in the SET section are evaluated in the order in which they are written. So `mycolumn` in the second expression is equal to the value set in the first expression. Simply switch expressions - `mycolumn_is_new =` first.

> Is it possible check the new and old value in a single query?

Yes, using user-defined variable. Save old, assign new, use old from variable and new from field. The simplest task need those method - switch the values of two fields in one UPDATE.